# asp.net dynamically button with event handler wont work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Hi I create button to fire event when user click on row.
It works when I create that "hidden" buttons on master page but when I create those buttons on MainContent it won't fire the event:

```
List<Button> btnCollection = new List<Button>();

protected void OnRowTask(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {        
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {


            string CellValue = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "id"));
            string urlAddress = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "url_address"));

            Button dummyBtn= new Button();
            dummyBtn.Attributes["style"] = "display:none;";
            dummyBtn.ID = "divBtn_" + CellValue;
            dummyBtn.Text = urlAddress;
            dummyBtn.Click += new EventHandler(this.rowButton_Click);
            PlaceHolderForHiddenBtn2.Controls.Add(dummyBtn);
            btnCollection.Add(divButton);

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return rowclick(" + CellValue + ");");

        }
        Session["hiddenBtnCollectionTask"] = btnCollection;
    }
```

Click event:

```
private void rowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//some code to exectute
}
```

On page load I create the same buttons what was added on row created event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["hiddenBtnCollectionTask"] != null)
        {
            List<Button> btnGenerateList = (List<Button>)Session["hiddenBtnCollectionTask"];
            foreach (Button btn in btnGenerateList)
            {
                PlaceHolderForHiddenBtn2.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
}
```

And JS function that should fire `button.click()` - event :

```
function rowclick(id) {
            var button = document.getElementById('MainContent_divBtn_' + id);
            button.click();

            return false;
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if `'MainContent_divBtn_' + id` actually exists? Because aspnet renames the ID of controls on the client side.

Comment: yes that button exist. I trired also fire this event just by clicking the button. But it also won't work.

Comment: ok Solved in page load in foreach function I add `btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.rowButton_Click);`